# Event.js:85 // Unhandled error event

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodes, handlebars.js

I'm working on a project, and everything was working just fine this friday. I wanted to continue today, and tried to "Gulp watch" in the terminal.

I recieve this error:

```
  events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
   Error
   at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Rasmus\desktop\sorthvid\fona\node_modules\gu
 lp-compile-handlebars\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\exception.js:2
6:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Rasmus\desktop\sorthvid\fona\node_modules\gu
lp-compile-handlebars\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\base.js:3:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I can't figure out the problem. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: this happened to me few time ago, You have the correct version of node.js

Answer (score 0):

```
Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yuyulei/Projects/Node/meadowlark/site/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/h    andlebars/exception.js:26:23)
        at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yuyulei/Projects/Node/meadowlark/site/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/base.js:3:17)
        at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
```

it's my error log. I think it's caused by Handlebars,like

```
{{#section 'jquery'}}
    <script>
    ......
    </script>
{{/section}}
```

then delete {{#section 'jquery'}} and {{/section}}, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber)
It gives you readable error messages. May be it will indicate where is the error.

More likely the error into your template.
I think [handlebars-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-cmd) can help you. Try to feed him your template. It must say you exactly, where's the error or at least hint about reason.